# getting url of browser

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm trying to add a filter between some servlets and jsp for the user logged in before displaying the jsp. The problem is that I am trying to retrieve the URL of the browser which that was forwarded to the login page, but I can't find how. I've tried to get the URI at the Filter and to send it as an attribute of a request to the **Connexion servlet** but, it doesn't work.

my **doFilter()**

```
package com.forum.filters;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class RestrictionFilter implements Filter {
    public static final String CONNEXION = "/WEB-INF/connexion.jsp";
    public static final String ATT_USER = "utilisateur";
    public static final String CHEMIN = "chemin";

    public void destroy() {

    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        String chemin = request.getRequestURI().substring(
                request.getContextPath().length());

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        if (session.getAttribute(ATT_USER) == null) {
            request.setAttribute(CHEMIN, chemin);
            request.getRequestDispatcher(CONNEXION).forward(request, response);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

}
```

my **Connexion servlet**

```
package com.forum.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.forum.beans.Utilisateur;
import com.forum.form.ConnexionForm;

public class Connexion extends HttpServlet {
    public static final String ATT_USER = "utilisateur";
    public static final String ATT_FORM = "form";
    public static final String VUE = "/WEB-INF/connexion.jsp";

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE)
                .forward(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        ConnexionForm form = new ConnexionForm();
        String chemin = (String) request.getAttribute("chemin");

        Utilisateur utilisateur = form.connecterUtilisateur(request);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        if (form.getErreurs().isEmpty()) {
            session.setAttribute(ATT_USER, utilisateur);
            if (chemin == null || chemin.startsWith("/connexion"))
                response.sendRedirect("/projetForum/forum");
            else
                response.sendRedirect("/projetForum" + chemin);
        } else {
            request.setAttribute(ATT_USER, null);
            request.setAttribute(ATT_FORM, form);
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE)
                    .forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

some tags of **web.xml**

```
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>Connexion</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.forum.servlets.Connexion</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Connexion</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/connexion</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
     <filter-name>RestrictionFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>com.forum.filters.RestrictionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>RestrictionFilter</filter-name>
     <servlet-name>Nouveau</servlet-name>
     <servlet-name>Profil</servlet-name>
     <servlet-name>Editer</servlet-name>
     <servlet-name>Repondre</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I couldn't comprehend your question: _I am trying to retrieve the URL of the browser with which he was forwarded to the login page but I get anywhere from just now_

Comment: Oh sorry, i've updated my post. I hope this is more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I see from your filter you already stored the referrer URL using `request.setAttribute(CHEMIN, chemin);` before you dispatch it to login page. In this case on your login jsp (I'm assuming this is /WEB-INF/connexion.jsp) you can just insert it as a form hidden field:

```
<form ...>
  <input type="hidden" name="referrer" value="<%= request.getAttribute("chemin") %>"/>
   ...
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, you can retrieve the referrer URL via 'referrer' request parameter

Comment: I've tested the way in which I setted the referre URL doesn't work

Comment: Updated my answer to use `<%= request.getAttribute("chemin") %>`. I think if you use request dispatcher EL does not evaluate properly